# Как вывести массив в yii2 gridView средствами самого грида?

Tags: php, yii2, grid

yii2, необходимо вывести массив, связанный с помощью joinWith:

```
    $model = Products::find()
        ->where(['product.id' => $id])
        ->joinWith('productsBarcodes')
        ->one();

    return $this->render('view', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
```

view:

```
foreach ($model->productsBarcodes as $item) {
    echo $item->barcode . '<br>';
}
```

сделал еще так:

```
        [
            'attribute' => 'productsBarcodes.barcode',
            'value' => function ($model){
                $arr = [];
                echo '<pre>';
                foreach ($model->productsBarcodes as $key => $item) {
                    $arr[$key] = $item->barcode;
                }
                $str = implode(',', $arr);
                return $str;
            }
        ],
```

все работает, но можно ли нормально выводить это в поле gridView средствами самого gridViw, а не анонимной функцией?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

видимо, никак. оставил как в вопросе.

upd: молодой был, глупый.

можно было вынести код анонимки в геттер getBarcodes и потом прописать в columns свойство 'barcodes'

Comment: Если ответа пока нет, не значит, что никак нельзя. А вот ваш ответ на ответ вообще не тянет =/

Comment: @Suvitruf, почему же не тянет? как раз таки такой ответ подразумевает, что решение, описанное в вопросе, возможно, единственное. ну или хотя бы не самое плохое. да и скорее всего реально никак не получится по другому вывести, так что почему бы и нет.

Answer (score 1):

Т.к нужно было обработать массив, до отправки в представление в ArrayDataProvider уже приходит сформированный.

```
return $this->render('index/new-returning', [
            'filterForm' => $filterForm,
            'dataProvider' => new ArrayDataProvider([
                'allModels' => $query,
                'pagination' => [
                    'pageSize' => 50,
                ],
            ]),
        ]);
```

А теперь про вывод через GridView

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            [
                'value' => function ($data) {
                    return $data['date'];
                },
            ],
        ]
    ]); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Блин, если я правильно поняла, что нужно вывести инфу из бд в gridView то:

В контроллере

> use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider; //подключаем

```
   $query = your_bd::find(); //нужные действия с бд
   $model = new ActiveDataProvider([
      'query' => $query,
      'pagination' => [
             'pageSize' => 5,
       ],
       'sort' => [
            'defaultOrder' => [
            'your_id' => SORT_DESC, //сортировка по нужному id
         ]
        ],
      ]);
    return $this->render('view', ['model' => $model]);
}
```

в view

```
<?php 

    use yii\grid\GridView;
    ?>

<?php
   echo GridView::widget([
       'dataProvider' => $model,
       'columns' => [
           ['attribute' => 'your_id'],
           [
               'label' => 'Название',
               'attribute' => 'your_column_1',
               'value' => function($data){return $data->your_column_1;} //название столбца из бд
           ],
           [
               'label' => 'Описание',
               'attribute' => 'your_column_2',
               'value' => function($data){return $data->your_column_2;}
           ],
           ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn']
       ]
   ])
?>
```

Comment: не совсем. выводить в гриды я умею.
меня интересует вывод значений, притянутых по внешним ключам, в гриды с помощью встроенных методов, а не самописной анонимной функции.